# Как можно связаться с участником форума, написать ему личное сообщение?

Tags: поддержка

Как можно связаться с участником форума, написать ему личное сообщение?

Comment: Никак, здесь нет личных сообщений. Если у вас есть вопрос — опубликуйте как вопрос. Если что-то иное, то попробуйте найти человека в чате. Возможно, в профиле участника есть контактная информация. Если нужно связаться с модератором или сотрудниками — используйте тревогу или [форму связи с поддержкой](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/contact)

Comment: подскажите, KoVadim, модератор или сотрудник или рядовой форумчанин?

Comment: Просто участник (ромба нет, значит не модератор). К слову, Stack Overflow – это не форум. Мы специально «открестились» от этого названия, чтобы подчеркнуть, что у нас формат вопросов и ответов, а не бесконечных дискуссий в темах (тредах).

Comment: Вот смотрите. Если вы хотите от KoVadim каких-то уточнений по его ответу, то комментируйте ответ, особенно если он на ваш вопрос. Если у вас есть вопрос, на который он наверняка знаете ответ — задайте этот вопрос на сайте, чтобы все могли ответ прочитать.

Comment: предложить сотрудничать, будет уместно в Коментарии его ответа на мой вопрос?

Comment: Можно создать чат и пригласить в него участника

Comment: @Grundy и таким образом немного "подкреститься" к форуму обратно :)